# Is it possible to make readline ignore compspec when expanding matches in VI mode?

Tags: bash, readline, vi-mode

I use VI mode when using bash and I sometimes find that some of the standard compspec definitions don't do what I want.  For example, `java` doesn't appear to know that you have been able to do `java Source.java` since Java 9.

Is there a way to get "dumb" expansion when in VI mode.  In emacs mode, I understand I can do `ESC /` and it will expand files without going through the `compspec` function.  But that doesn't work in VI mode (the `ESC` just ends normal mode).

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out.  The readline function to call is `complete-filename`, so I can create a mapping in my `.inputrc`:

```
$if mode=vi
    set keymap vi-insert
    "\C- ": complete-filename
$endif
```